# Argument Parser error: "the following arguments are required:"

Tags: arguments, argparse

**I am newer to coding and can't figure out what to fix about my code to make this run. The error that I keep getting is this:**

```
usage: submit.py [-h] [--username USERNAME] [--password PASSWORD]
                 [--location LOCATION] [--dry-run] [--report REPORT]
                 [--https | --http]
                 assign [tasks ...]
submit.py: error: the following arguments are required: assign
```

**Below is the snippet of my program that the error is referring to, namely the line parser.add_argument('assign', help=next(ihelp))**

```
import argparse
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    helps = [ 'assignment name'
            , 'numbers or ranges of problems/tasks to submit'
            , 'your username (you can make one up)'
            , 'your password (optional)'
            , 'your geographical location (optional, used for mapping activity)'
            , 'display tests without actually running them'
            , 'specify where to send the results'
            , 'use an encrypted connection to the grading server'
            , 'use an unencrypted connection to the grading server'
            ]
    ihelp = iter(helps)
    parser.add_argument('assign', help=next(ihelp))
    parser.add_argument('tasks', default=profile.get('TASKS',None), nargs='*', help=next(ihelp))
    parser.add_argument('--username', '--login', default=profile.get('USERNAME',None), help=next(ihelp))
    parser.add_argument('--password', default=profile.get('PASSWORD',None), help=next(ihelp))
    parser.add_argument('--location', default=profile.get('LOCATION',None), help=next(ihelp))
    parser.add_argument('--dry-run', default=False, action='store_true', help=next(ihelp))
    parser.add_argument('--report', default=profile.get('REPORT',None), help=next(ihelp))
    group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
    group.add_argument('--https', dest="protocol", const="https", action="store_const", help=next(ihelp))
    group.add_argument('--http', dest="protocol", const="http", action="store_const", help=next(ihelp))

    parser.add_argument('--verbose', default=False, action='store_true', help=argparse.SUPPRESS)
    parser.add_argument('--show-submission', default=False, action='store_true', help=argparse.SUPPRESS)
    parser.add_argument('--show-feedback', default=False, action='store_true', help=argparse.SUPPRESS)

    args = parser.parse_args()
    asgn_name = os.path.splitext(args.assign)[0]
    report = args.report
    location = args.location
    dry_run = args.dry_run
```

I have tried some things from the internet like changing the line into this: args = parser.parse_args(args) and I have tried adding a default=profile to the assign line like the rest of the parser lines, but that didn't change the error.

I would really welcome any help, as I need to get this fixed by tonight!

Comment: How do call this script?  Do you know what `commandline arguments` are?  Or even the basic purpose of this `argparse` usage?

Comment: You have to provide a `assign` string, which from the `asgn_name` line should be something like `one/two`  But judging from the error, you are calling this script without such a commandline value.  Often people have problems like this when the invoke the script via a IDE like `spyder`.  Did you copy this code from some where, maybe a tutorial?  It's too complex to be written by someone who is new to coding.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you are trying to do.

If all you want is to make it run then you can simply add `nargs="?"` to the `assign` argument declaration.  This however will make the argument optional, which may or may not be your intention.

```
parser.add_argument('assign', help=next(ihelp), nargs="?", default=profile.get("Some Default Value"))
```